# Efficiently Organize TikZ Nodes in Beamer Presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, miktex

The following minimal example comiles:

```
\documentclass[c]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,times}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
    },
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{StateNormal} = [fill=white]
\tikzstyle{StateSelected} = [fill=orange]

\coordinate (ONE) at (0,0);
\coordinate (TWO) at (4,0);
\coordinate (THREE) at (8,0);

\draw (ONE) -- (TWO) -| (THREE);

\draw
    node at (ONE)                      [StateSelected, visible on=<1>]{ONE}
    node at (ONE)                      [StateNormal, visible on=<2->]{ONE}
    node at (TWO)                      [StateSelected, visible on=<2>]{TWO}
    node at (TWO)                      [StateNormal, visible on=<3->]{TWO}
    node at (THREE)                    [StateSelected, visible on=<3>]{THREE}
    node at (THREE)                    [StateNormal, visible on=<4->]{THREE}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

%DO NOT INDENT THE END OF A FRAGILE FRAME
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have a couple of problems with this example and i dont know how to go about solving them:

I define each node twice only so it has different properties on different slides.
There is redundancy there and all i know how to fix it is a new command.
It seems like a common problem - is there another standars solution?

```
    node at (ONE)                      [StateSelected, visible on=<1>]{ONE}
    node at (ONE)                      [StateNormal, visible on=<2->]{ONE}
```

My next problem is that there is always a connection between numbers.
If i want to insert a slide at the front end i have to rename all the slides from there until the end.

```
    node at (ONE)                      [StateSelected, visible on=<1>]{ONE}
    node at (ONE)                      [StateNormal, visible on=<2->]{ONE}
    node at (TWO)                      [StateSelected, visible on=<2>]{TWO}
    node at (TWO)                      [StateNormal, visible on=<3->]{TWO}
    node at (THREE)                    [StateSelected, visible on=<3>]{THREE}
    node at (THREE)                    [StateNormal, visible on=<4->]{THREE}
```

If i insert here this would create a new list with huge renaming effort.

```
    node at (ZERO)                     [StateSelected, visible on=<1>]{ZERO}
    node at (ZERO)                     [StateNormal, visible on=<2->]{ZERO}
    node at (ONE)                      [StateSelected, visible on=<2>]{ONE}
    node at (ONE)                      [StateNormal, visible on=<3->]{ONE}
    node at (TWO)                      [StateSelected, visible on=<3>]{TWO}
    node at (TWO)                      [StateNormal, visible on=<4->]{TWO}
    node at (THREE)                    [StateSelected, visible on=<4>]{THREE}
    node at (THREE)                    [StateNormal, visible on=<5->]{THREE}
```

I would want to write:

```
    count = 1;      
    node at (ZERO)  [StateSelected, visible on=<(count)>]{ZERO}
    node at (ZERO)  [StateNormal, visible on=<(count+1)->]{ZERO}
    count ++;       
    node at (ONE)   [StateSelected, visible on=<(count)>]{ONE}
    node at (ONE)   [StateNormal, visible on=<(count+1)->]{ONE}
    count ++;       
    node at (TWO)   [StateSelected, visible on=<(count)>]{TWO}
    node at (TWO)   [StateNormal, visible on=<(count+1)->]{TWO}
    count ++;       
    node at (THREE) [StateSelected, visible on=<(count)>]{THREE}
    node at (THREE) [StateNormal, visible on=<(count+1)->]{THREE}
```

but i dont know how to write such statements in MikTex.

Comment: For the second problem: have you read the beamer manual on overlay specs? You can use the special `+` and `.` symbols to mean "the next overlay" and "the current one"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\temporal` instead of `\alt` to specify a "before" "on slide" and "after" style and use that directly to avoid duplication of nodes.

To avoid hardcoding of slide numbers just use the special overlay specification `+` which means "insert a new slide and refer to the new one as the reference for the spec":

```
\documentclass[c]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz,times}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    temporal/.code args={<#1>#2#3#4}{
    \temporal<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#4}}
    },
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{StateNormal} = [fill=white]
\tikzstyle{StateSelected} = [fill=orange]

\coordinate (ONE) at (0,0);
\coordinate (TWO) at (4,0);
\coordinate (THREE) at (8,0);

\draw (ONE) -- (TWO) -| (THREE);

\draw
    node at (ONE)   [temporal=<+>{invisible}{StateSelected}{StateNormal}]{ONE}
    node at (TWO)   [temporal=<+>{invisible}{StateSelected}{StateNormal}]{TWO}
    node at (THREE) [temporal=<+>{invisible}{StateSelected}{StateNormal}]{THREE}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

%DO NOT INDENT THE END OF A FRAGILE FRAME
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can even make the syntax more readable by defining the following styles:

```
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    normal/.style={fill=white},
    selected/.style={fill=orange},
    temporal/.code args={<#1>#2#3#4}{%
        \temporal<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#4}}
    },
    change style/.code args={start #1 then on <#2> to #3 and after to #4}{\temporal<#2>{\pgfkeysalso{#1}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#4}}},
    reveal on/.style={change style=start invisible then on #1 to selected and after to normal},
    reveal/.style={reveal on=<+>}
  }
```

And your code becomes

```
\draw
    node at (ONE)   [reveal]{ONE}
    node at (TWO)   [reveal]{TWO}
    node at (THREE) [reveal]{THREE}
    ;
```

If you want something to be revealed on slide 2 you can use the style `reveal on=<2>` and if you want to make something visible only between slide 3 and 5 you can do `change style=start invisible then on <3-5> to normal and after to invisible`.